# Awk command for combining lines and summarizing them

Tags: linux, scripting, awk

This is the format that I have.

```
Source IP       Destination IP    Received Sent
192.168.0.1     10.10.10.1        3412     341
192.168.0.1     10.10.10.1        341      43
192.168.0.1     10.22.22.2        34       334
192.168.0.1     192.168.9.3       34       243
```

But a very large file of these. I basically want to give the total bandwidth of each source IP. So I need to combine all uniq source IPs and then add the received columns of everything that is unique and then add the sent columns. The end outcome would be:

source ip - total received packets - total sent packets

It would also be nice to uniq the source and destination IP as well so I could also get

source ip - destination ip - total received packets - total sent packets

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

just looking at the Source IP:

```
awk '
    NR == 1 {next}
    {
        recv[$1] += $3
        sent[$1] += $4
    }
    END {for (ip in recv) printf("%s - %d - %d\n", ip, recv[ip], sent[ip]}
' filename
```

for source/destination pairs, just a slight modification:

```
awk '
    NR == 1 {next}
    {
        key = $1 " - " $2
        recv[key] += $3
        sent[key] += $4
    }
    END {for (key in recv) printf("%s - %d - %d\n", key, recv[key], sent[key])}
' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby      
hash_recv=Hash.new(0)
hash_sent=Hash.new(0)
hash_src_dst_recv=Hash.new(0)
hash_src_dst_sent=Hash.new(0)
f=File.open("file")
f.readline
f.each do |line|
    s = line.split
    hash_recv[s[0]] += s[2].to_i
    hash_sent[s[0]] +=  s[-1].to_i
    hash_src_dst_recv[ s[0,2] ] +=  s[2].to_i
    hash_src_dst_sent[ s[0,2] ] +=  s[-1].to_i
end
f.close
p hash_recv
p hash_sent
p hash_src_dst_recv
p hash_src_dst_sent
```

test run:

```
$ ruby test.rb
{"192.168.0.1"=>3787, "192.168.168.0.1"=>34}
{"192.168.0.1"=>718, "192.168.168.0.1"=>243}
{["192.168.0.1", "10.10.10.1"]=>3753, ["192.168.0.1", "10.22.22.2"]=>34, ["192.168.168.0.1", "192.168.9.3"]=>34}
{["192.168.0.1", "10.10.10.1"]=>384, ["192.168.0.1", "10.22.22.2"]=>334, ["192.168.168.0.1", "192.168.9.3"]=>243}
```

Comment: @MJB, OP did also put a tag on "scripting". It doesn't necessarily need to be `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a (a little bit formatted but you could write it in one line):

```
sort file.txt | awk ' BEGIN {start = 1;} 
                           { 
                            ip = $1; 
                            if (lastip == ip) { 
                               sum_r += $3; sum_s += $4; 
                               }
                            else 
                               { if (!start) print lastip ": " sum_r ", " sum_s
                                 else 
                                    start = 0;
                                 lastip = ip; sum_r = $3; sum_s = $4;
                                }
                            }
                       END { print lastip ": " sum_r ", " sum_s }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk '{
       if (NR==FNR){ 
         Recieved[$1,$2]+=$3;Sent[$1,$2]+=$4;
       }else{
           if(Recieved[$1,$2]){
             print $1" " $2" " Recieved[$1,$2]" "Sent[$1,$2];Recieved[$1,$2]=""
           }
       }
      }' InputFile.txt InputFile.txt
```

InputFile is read twice hence it is added two times at the end.
The first occurence of inputfile (*which is used in if(NR==FNR) condition*) is to build the two arrays and second inputfile (*used in else condition*) is to print all the combinations and also setting the array value to blank so that we wont print again.

Glenn's Solution below is much superior it reads the file only once